# Insert Search component inside of another component

Tags: sxa

I am trying to create a heading element on a page which contains of a background image, title and search box component. Our UI developer advised us to put searchbox into the same div element as image.

I tried to use placeholder in the variant to render image, title and place search box in the placeholder however the placeholder is not being displayed on the page.

There is no error message in the logs and in the console. I tried searching about how Placeholder works on doc.sitecore.net  but could not find any good resource. Can you please explain how the placeholder within a variant works? Or provide some good resource where I could read about it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you going to use this variant for displaying multiple results? I am not sure whether you are solving your challenges with right tools

Comment: Make sure the placeholder key for the new placeholder is in the placeholder setting folder. And that it's editable.